# STS 3.6.3 (Eclipse 4.4.1) updates fails with CollectAction error

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, java-7, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I try to update the Eclipse 4.4.1 distribution Springsource Tool Suite 3.6.3.SR1 32bit on jdk 1.7 in Windows 7 installed in the program folder, with write protection off and full permissions for owner, users and trusted installer,  after I've chosen the updates I want and clicked "finish" I immediately get this message and the operation is aborted:

> "An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=DefaultProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect,
>   operand=[R]com.ibm.icu 52.1.0.v201404241930 --> [R]com.ibm.icu
>   52.1.1.v201501240615, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.CollectAction).
>   comma not allowed in id comma not allowed in id"

It would seem to be a bug regarding an URL String somewhere but there's no entry in the [issuetracker] that I can find.[1](https://issuetracker.springsource.com)

Any advice for how to resolve this is welcome as I now can't set up my environment the way I need it with installing updates and additional software into Eclipse (STS).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this turns out to be a Windows 7 issue. While previously on Windows 7 (years back) turning off write protection and giving full access to the owner has been sufficient, it wasn't this time. Running STS from outside of "program" works out. I*d prefer to have STS in the Program folder, but at least I can code now. I'll revisit the proper settings for the program folder later.